# Font size in new theme?

Tags: support, design, markdown-preview, font

Is there something funny about font  size in the new "theme",  or is it a problem at my end or what?

These days when I write/edit a post the preview looks the same as always. Then when I "save edit" the equations in the post suddenly appear much larger than they did in the preview... like inline equations are much larger than the surrounding text - not a big problem, just looks funny. (Look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2883898/let-u-be-an-open-connected-set-in-mathbbc-the-following-are-equivalent/2883976#2883976) for example; here the $C$ in the first sentence is much larger than the *C* in the second sentence. Does it look that way to you as well?)

(Just  checking whether the same problem appears here on meta: $x^2+y^2=1$. Nope, looks fine here.)

Comment: Right-click on a math formula. When the context menu pops up go to Math Settings->Zoom Factor. Compare the values on main and on meta. I guess it's a higher value for you on main.

Comment: The C's have pretty much the same size for me. Supports my guess.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks. Changing the Zoom Factor seems to have no effect, perhaps because Zoom Trigger is "No Zoom". I'm probably being punished for https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2876970/how-can-i-expand-ej-beta-sin-wt-using-mathematica/2878352#2878352 .

Comment: @DanielFischer No wait - changing Zoom Factor and then reloading it fixes it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

We also have smaller text in the question lists.  Here are three samples, and of course math.se is smallest...

[image: MO]

[image: math]

[image: academia]